# Problems with gotoAndStop and MOUSE_OVER

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi am pretty new to actionscript and I am am trying to create a web banner that when rolled over a panel with text will silde up from the bottom and when rolled out will slide away again...

```
blank_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fl_MouseOverHandler);  
   function fl_MouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
   {    gotoAndPlay("start");   
   trace("Moused over"); 
   }  
   stop();  
   blank_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fl_MouseOutHandler);  
   function fl_MouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
   {    
   gotoAndPlay("Finished")  
   trace("Moused out"); 
   }  
   stop();
```

at the moment all it does is play the slide in and disappear. I want the Mouse over gotoAndPlay to only play a selected chunk of the animation (the slide in) and I want the Mouse Out gotoAndPlay to play the slide out...

Hope this make sense!

Comment: so the above code is inside that banner that it plays? The problem with something like this is when a rollout occurs before the first anim has finished..it's not very slick. Have you put stop(); commands on the last frames of each anim segment?

Comment: I have managed to get the roll in to work but not the rollout now. I had put the stop functions in the same frame on the time line rather than further down the timeline...

Comment: is the  blank_btn on it's  own layer with no keyframes and spanning the whole length of the movieclip?

Comment: Hi yes it covers the entire movie...

Comment: so is there a stop on frame one and also on the frame before Finished? And does the finished label have a capital F? If you tell flash to go to a frame and play that has a stop on it, it wont override it. In the same mention, if there is a stop on frame 1 then start should be on frame 2 for this to work continuosly